# Searching a Pandas DataFrame column for empty values gives contradictory results

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, kaggle

I'm trying to clean [test data from Kaggle's Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data), specifically the columns - sex, fare, pclass, and age. In order to do this, I'd like to find out if any of these columns have empty values. I load the data:

```
import pandas as pd
test_address = 'path_to_data\test.csv'
test = pd.read_csv(test_address)
```

When I try to look for empty values in the columns,

```
True in test['Sex'].isna()
```

outputs True.

However,

```
test['Sex'].isna().value_counts()
```

outputs

```
False    418
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

which should mean there aren't any empty values (I could confirm this by visually scanning the csv file). These commands on `test['Pclass']` have similar outputs.

Why is the 'True in' command giving me the wrong answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `in`, when applied to a Series, checks if its left operand is in the *index* of the right operand. Since there is a row #1 (the numeric representation of `True`) in the series, the operator evaluates to True.

For the same reason `False in df['Sex'].isna()` is `True`, but `False in df['Sex'][1:].isna()` is `False` (there is no row #0 in the latter slice).

You should check if `True in df['Sex'].isna().values`.

Comment: Great, thanks @DyZ. `True in test['Sex'].isna().values` works as expected (gives `False`). So do `False in test['Sex'][1:].isna()` (`False`) and `True in test['Sex'].isna()[2:]` (`False`)!